# React hooks useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

The doubt is , in the webpage the value gets incremented and displays but in console it displays the previous value......what am i not understanding ?

when i click on the button , in the webpage the value gets incremented but whereas at the console output it's still the previous value :/

```
function App() {
  function handleClick()
  {
 
    setValue((prev)=>prev+1)
    console.log(value)

  }
  const [value,setValue]=useState(0);
  return (

    <div className="App" style={{fontSize:"100px"}}>
      {value}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: updated state will be available in the next render, you can place your `console.log` outside of `handleClick` and check the resutl

Comment: if you want to see the updated value move `console.log` out of the function

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera yes to some extent but its pretty complicated to get around, the simple answer it seems useState is asynchronous function

Answer (score 5):

This is beacause `setValuse` is async function, and value in state will be update in next renderer.

Check this:

```
  function handleClick()
  {
 
    setValue((prev)=>prev+1)
    console.log(value)

  }
  const [value,setValue]=useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => { console.log(value)}, [value])
```

Comment: so, all the hooks are async functions ? or just useState ?

Comment: Hooks it's a normal function, and everything it's depends on what kind of hook you use. setState is async function because of how react state works ;)